# How to wrap a C struct that contains a C++ object in python ctypes

Tags: python, c++, struct, stl, ctypes

I have a C/C++ structure which contains an object (an STL container, for example.)  I would like to access this from Python using ctypes.  For example,

C/C++:

```
struct Foo {
  int bar;
  vector<int> baz;
  double quxx;
}
```

Python ctypes:

```
from ctypes import *

class Foo(Structure):
  _fields_ = [
    ("bar", c_int),
    ("baz", ???),  <--- what do i put here?
    ("quxx", c_double),]
```

I realize I can't access STL containers using ctypes without creating wrapper functions, but it'd be nice to be able to access "bar" and "quxx."  The only way I've been able to do this is to only deal with opaque pointers and wrapper functions, e.g.

C/C++:

```
int Foo_bar(*Foo foo) { return foo->bar; }
...
```

Python

```
class Foo_p(c_void_p): pass
my_Foo_p = ... somehow get a Foo pointer ...
bar = mylib.Foo_bar(my_Foo_p)
```

This seems clumsy.  Is there a way to create a ctypes.Structure for C structs which contain C++ objects?  Maybe using sizeof?

Comment: Why exactly do you need that? You won't be able to use `Foo` objects in any reliable way anyhow if the contained C++ object has a non-trivial constructor or destructor.

Comment: I understand constructing and destructing such an object is impossible from Python, but all I want to do is access its members that are basic C types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it contains a C++ class as a member, it is *not* a C-struct. `struct` and `class` are identical keywords except that `struct` defaults to `public` for all members rather than `private`.

That said, if you're willing to risk nasal demons if you get it wrong, you could use hidden knowledge. In both of the major libraries used on unixy platforms, `vector` internally contains three pointers, so you could use that. I have no idea what Windows implementations use, but Windows doesn't have a stable ABI anyway.

Comment: isnt vector just 1 pointer and size_t? I dont see need for 2 other pointers, since vector is always allocated as contiguous block of memory, not Linked list or other data structure

Comment: @TheOne it needs a capacity as well as a size. It makes no real difference since `sizeof(void *) == sizeof(size_t)`, but for internal implementation purposes it turns out that it's mildly easier to store pointers for end-of-used-data and end-of-allocation than it is to store integers. Admittedly a part of this is just the iterator-pair mindset though.

Comment: ah yea I forgot about capacity.

Comment: You are right, "C/C++ structure" is not precise.  As you surmised, what I want to exploit is the fact that the memory layout for C structs and C++ objects is "the same", so if i knew sizeof(vector<int>) and the layout I should be able to access the C parts of a C++ object.  But as you also point out this is probably fragile and I should just use an opaque interface.  Thanks, I'll accept your answer.